# Can we run a voice assistant in django template?

Tags: python, django

I have made a django website and I am rendering a template with html animation in front , linked to css.
Now I want that when my template opens my python script of the voice assistant also starts executing . is is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to run a python voice assistant *on the webpage* or in the background?

Comment: in the background of webpage and i want to display an animation in the front of the webpage